# How to check change in class name using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

Need to test change in class name after particular action is performed. 
In my application , after a button is pressed the footer progress bar shows progress .

the only change in footer code is change in class name . following is the code snippet:

Before:

```
<i class="fa fa-check-circle pull-left" ng-class="{processComplete : sent}"></i>
```

After process is complete:

```
<i class="fa fa-check-circle pull-left processComplete" ng-class="{processComplete : sent}"></i>
```

How to test the change in class name using protractor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check that an element with `processComplete` class *is present*:

```
expect(element(by.css('.processComplete')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Or, you can check that a particular element has `processComplete` class:

```
expect(element(by.css('i.fa.fa-check-circle')).getAttribute('class')).not.toMatch('processComplete');

// perform some action

expect(element(by.css('i.fa.fa-check-circle')).getAttribute('class')).toMatch('processComplete');
```